# inotify used by vscode and web service for changes in same file

Tags: inotify, visual-studio-code

I use a web server and `inotify` to check for files changing and posting the new content. It works well if I change the files with an ordinary editor (e.g. `pluma`): the changed file is posted.
If I use `VScode` to edit the files - because it is more powerful - changes are not posted. I assume `VScode` on a linux box uses internally `inotify` (the files are in the local filesystem) and there is a conflict.

Is there a method to have `inotify` watch for changes in the same set of files for two different processes? Or is there a way to force `VScode` to trigger the notification?

Comment: The kernel should not care whether there are multiple processes all looking at the same file. If it is not working,then I would assume your method is wrong. Please update the question and tell us what is triggering the event. I would hazard a guess and say that VSCode is overwriting the existing file and preserving the inode number.

Comment: Thank you for your guess! I will ask now specifically on VScode.

Comment: There is no need. Run `stat` against  a file and check the inode, then have vscode update it, then recheck the inode. You have not told us yes how you are calling `inotify`. Without that, you can ask anything you want and you'll not get an answer. DON'T DRIPFEED INFORMATION.

Comment: Your suggestion had me switch off `autosave` in VScode. When I `save` changes manually, `inotify` for the web server is triggered and the server updated. Problem solved - thank you!

Comment: @Bib - your advice to check the inode is useful; I am not a specialist on `inotifiy` - I added it without fully understanding how it works; neither did I understand how VScode manages files in detail. Therefore I could not ask more precisely .. but I got information which was extremely helpful and lead to a quick solution.